# I have two django authentication backends. How can I put Condition for which one to use on my particular web page.?

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

What can I write in views or settings.py which auth system to use ??

This is my views.py

```
@require_POST
def login_view(request):
    filled_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if filled_form.is_valid():
        user = filled_form.get_user()
        login(request,user)
        context = { 'user': user }
        return render(request,'home.html',context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Does not Exist")
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS =   ['accounts.backends.TeacherBackend','accounts.backends.StudentBackend']
```

backends.py

```
class StudentBackend(object):
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    print("AT STUDENT BACK")
    try:
        student = Student.objects.get(student_id=username)
    except Student.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    if student.check_password(password):
        return student
    else:
        return None


def get_user(self, student_id):
    try:
        return Student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
    except Student.DoesNotExist:
        return None


class TeacherBackend(object):
print("AT TEACHER BACK")
   def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
      try:
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(email=username)
      except Teacher.DoesNotExist:
        return None
      if teacher.check_password(password):
        return teacher
      else:
        return None


   def get_user(self, teacher_id):
     try:
        return Teacher.objects.get(pk=teacher_id)
     except UsTeacherer.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Please tell me How can I write code which decides which backend to call ??

Please don't read stack overflow was forcing me to write more description but I was not able to think any so in a way I am writing this dummy text as description. Keep cool. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, how do you WANT it to work? Do teachers and students have different login forms? Views?

Comment: Oh! this is an idea different model forms. Let me try! Thanks

Comment: Good luck! You need to have some sort of way to differentiate how to separate the two. Forms seems to be the way IMO. Let us know how you accomplish it.

Comment: Django will always try every auth backend until a user is returned or `PermissionDenied` is raised. You can't skip one, but the auth backend can return `None` if certain conditions aren't met.

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate the login types in the login form. One way is using a drop down box in the login form. To do that a custom field has to be added in the login form:

In forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class CustomLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    # Choose login type
    login_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=(
            ('student', 'Student'),
            ('teacher', 'Teacher')
        )
    )
```

In views.py

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_form = CustomLoginForm
```

in urls.py

```
url(r'^login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login')
```

In backends.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class StudentBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        print("AT STUDENT BACK")
        if self.request.POST.login_type != 'student':
            return None
        try:
            student = Student.objects.get(student_id=username)
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            raise PermissionDenied("No such student exists") # Stop executing other backends
        if student.check_password(password):
            return student
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied("Wront credentials for student")


    def get_user(self, student_id):
        try:
            return Student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            return None

class TeacherBackend:
   def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
      print("AT TEACHER BACK")
      if self.request.POST.login_type != 'teacher':
        return None
      try:
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(email=username)
      except Teacher.DoesNotExist:
        raise PermissionDenied("No such teacher exists")
      if teacher.check_password(password):
        return teacher
      else:
        raise PermissionDenied("Wront credentials for teacher")


   def get_user(self, teacher_id):
     try:
        return Teacher.objects.get(pk=teacher_id)
     except UsTeacherer.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

In settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS =   [
    'accounts.backends.TeacherBackend',
    'accounts.backends.StudentBackend'
    # ... Any other following backends
    ]
```

In templates/registration/login.html

```
# ... Include with other Login fields
{{ form.login_type }}
```

Django checks each back ends in the given order and if any back end raises PermissionDenied exception the execution will stop. So each login type will be validated only by the appropriate back end.